# query referer data in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am trying to get data from a url ( banner with sourceID,CampaignID in the url)
Example:
http://where-my-banner-is.com/banner.jpeg?sourceID=10&campaignID=11

I need to grab this data and append to my wordpress url and have it stay with the user until they fill in the form on my page (which could be anywhere) So a form of tracking the source ID and campaign ID from where the user came from(the banner URL)

To simplify:
My CRM needs to know where this lead came from and what campaign it is on (all that info will be in the reffering URL, unfortunately the company I work for will not budge on using their own in house CRM as I know there are plugins that do all of this.

So far I have

```
<?php
$sourceID = $_GET['sourceID'];
<span style="color:#0D40E1; font-size:18px;"> <?php echo 'The sourceID is '. $sourceID; ?></span>
?>
```

which shows me that I can get the data from the url and store it to a variable 
but I have no idea how to append this data in query form to the wordpress urls after that and keep them with the user during their stay

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: @FelipeElia Updated original